# What is the generating functional for a scalar theory with two different (interacting and real) fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, greens-functions

My question is specifically about how to use sources? For an interacting theory with one field, one puts a $J(x)\phi(x)$ term in the exponential in the path integral for $W[J]$. I now have two different fields ($\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(x)$) and a number of interactions in the Lagrangian involving a combination of fields up to fourth order. To calculate the appropriate Green's functions and Feynman rules, should I use two different sources so that I have terms $J_1(x)\phi_1(x) + J_2(x)\phi_2(x)$?

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you want to do is to bring down $\psi_1(x)$ and/or $\psi_2(x)$ and you do that by multiplying them by independent currents and integrating over space-time, which then allows you to take the functional derivative w.r.t. either of the currents independently.

This is completely analogous to   $\int J(x) \psi(x) d^4 x$, you now have a discrete index in addition to the continuous variable $x$.